# Combine relationship posts with existing wp_query

Tags: wp-query, array

So I am building a query, and I wanted to see if someone can assist me on a special attempt to infuse two queries.

So here is what I'm attempting to do:

1. Check if we have any relationship posts, which I can return either an `array of IDs` or an `array of WP_Post objects`.
2. I want to showcase the relationship posts first if they are and then showcase the remaining wp_query posts.

Here is what I'm working with:

---

**Original**:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => ['work', Report_Type::CPT_NAME],
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'post_status' => ['publish'],
];
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Then I'm looping through using a template as shown below:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part('template-parts/blocks/work-expertise-filter/work-items-template', null, ['query' => $query]);
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

---

So let's say, that I have `get_field('featured_posts')` which returns back an ARRAY of IDs (I can check it to ARRAY of WP_Post objects if needed).
This is our return: `array(2) { [0]=> int(14244) [1]=> int(14566) } array(4) {`

So I attemped to do something like this:

```
    $args = [
        'post_type' => ['work', Report_Type::CPT_NAME],
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'post_status' => ['publish'],
    ];
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    $all_ids = [];
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $all_ids[] = array_merge($query->post->ID, get_field('featured_posts'));
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    $all_ids = array_unique($all_ids);
    $args = [
        'post__in' => $all_ids
    ];
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But I'm getting no response back, it's basically: `object(WP_Query)#1853 (50) { [“query”]=> array(1) { [“post__in”]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL } } [“query_vars”]=> array(63) { [“post__in”]=> array(1) { [0]=> NULL }`

If someone could help me with a query, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Because in your second assignment of `$args` you didn't specify the `post_type`

Comment: Please don't edit your question into jibberish. If you wish to delete your question there is specifically a delete link toward the bottom of your post.

Comment: Have you confirmed the contents of `$all_ids` matches expectations? If you found a solution to your problem please post it as an answer below for other users with the same question